# I'm trying to dynamically allocate for static byte board[67] in a class

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

This line of code from this first of two .cpp files

static byte board[64+3]; ... more code  //board array of 67 is declared here

board is used in here

if ((board[FR(move)] == WHITE_PAWN && R(TO(move)) == RANK_8)

and further more in the code.

I'm trying to convert this into more of a object oriented program. First I'm trying to allocate for board in another .h and .cpp file

This is my board.h file

```
class Board
{
public:
Board();
private:
};
```

This is my other.cpp file

```
Board::Board() 

{

byte *board =new byte[67];

}
```

this is the error I get

mscp.cpp: In function ‘int search(int, int, int)’:

mscp.cpp:1649:26: error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope

for (i=ply-4; i>=board[LAST]; i-=2) {
                          ^
board.cpp: In constructor ‘Board::Board()’:
board.cpp:7:2: error: ‘byte’ was not declared in this scope

byte board =new byte[67];
  ^
board.cpp:7:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘board’

byte board =new byte[67];

Why can't my first .cpp file see board?

Comment: Is byte an user defined type here?? Because C++ dont have byte data type

Answer (score 0):

One of numerous errors here is that you have declared `board` to be a local variable in your constructor only. You need to make that a public member of the class `Board` if you want visibility outside your class.

PS: You are probably currently going to leak memory as well, even after sorting the other issues out! As you are not de-allocating the heap space you allocated at the end of your constructor when `board` goes out of scope.

Comment: @unluddite: Why have you posted this answer as a comment to my answer? The opening question is not my code?

Comment: Yikes, not sure what happened, must have thought I was responding to something else on the wrong page.